# A php function to insert or update mysql table on true/false

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to write a function to check whether a user exists in a table, if so, update the row, if not, insert it.

Here is my function:

```
        function UserExists($screenname){
            $mysql = mysql_fetch_array ( mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `screenname` = '$screenname' "));
                if($mysql){
                    return TRUE;
                }else{
                    return FALSE;
                }
}
```

And im executing this function using the following:

```
if(UserExists($user)){
mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET  `token` =  '$token' ,  `secret` =  '$secret'  WHERE `screenname` = '$user' ");
}else{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`screenname`, `token`, `secret`) VALUES ('$user', '$token', '$secret')");
}
```

Its not doing anything, not throwing any errors, but also not updating the table.

Answer (score 3):

You'd want to take a look at the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` [MySQL query syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) to make this work with just one query.

```
INSERT INTO users (screenname, token, secret) VALUES ('screenname', 'token', 'secret')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE token = 'token', secret = 'secret'
```

`screenname` should be unique (or a primary key) which you probably don't have at the moment. I suggest to add an ID column in your database table and use that to refer to database rows.

Answer (score 0):

Call `mysql_error` after the calls to see what error you are getting.  Also another good debugging technique is to execute it on the server using a MySQL client such as mysqlfront or phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Your best solution is ON DUPLICATE KEY as JoostK stated

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply suggest to use `REPLACE INTO SET col = val` in this case, all you need to do is define a unique index on the table.

The [Replace Command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html) will have a look at the unique indexes, if a row already exists it will update the existing, if not it will insert a new one.